# How could Giants hunt?

Tags: fantasy-races

In my story giants are about 13-14ft tall and weigh usually a little bit more or less than 1,000 pounds. Giants communicate through stomping their feet, and while running or walking through modulations of the footfall. Though while doing this the it would be the equivalent of being gagged while talking, other giants can understand what you're trying to say it sounds much more muffled. Giants also tend to be usually individualistic, and don't usually form very large groups. I was thinking of a few ways they could hide their massive size, maybe hiding underneath the grass waiting for something to walk over them. They could also simply raid villages for cows and sheeps, but I wanted hear others ideas on how such big and loud things could ever hunt anything.

Comment: Perhaps the majority of their diet isn't meat, so they don't have to be very good? And they spend a lot time eating plants?   Or perhaps they like fishing, and can sit quietly, or gather mussels or use nets. If clever perhaps they are good at making traps  or constructing fences in other ways to catch animals.

Comment: How fast can these giants run? They presumably have a large stride and could simply run their prey down.

Comment: https://deadliestwarrior.fandom.com/wiki/Pilum pilums are just spears with a half metal shaft, people were able to throw them at a decent distance. Taller humans have stronger muscles and better leverages, hence they could easily throw at further distances .  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)#:~:text=As%20a%20weapon%2C%20the%20sling,effective%20range%20of%20ancient%20weapons. ancient slingers could reach over 400+ meters in range(1300+ feet). For the same reason Giants could shoot even further and be considered snipers. Was my comment deleted because there were no sources?

Comment: Also slings can be incredibly primitive, you can easily make cordage from grass, nothing but grass, there's tutorials on youtube, I did it, you can ty it too... it's strong cordage! Strong enough to hold the weight of a person! and spears are just pointy sticks of wood.

Answer (score 15):

> others ideas on how such big and loud things could ever hunt anything

Why not take an example from humans, and have your giants be endurance predators? "*You can hide, but you can't run!*" sort of thing. They have excellent tracking skills, and follow big herds with long, efficient strides and tire their prey out til it just can't run anymore. If your giants follow a humanlike bodyplan, throwing seems like it would be an inevitable tool. Accurate, dangerous throwing is a bit of a human signature special move, compared to other animals.

Also, careful with "big and loud". Elephants are known for being kinda big, but they can move almost silently when they want... big feet and a relaxed pace work well in that regard. Your giants might not be ninja-like ambushers, but there's no reason that they have to clomp-clomp about everywhere if they didn't want to.

> They could also simply raid villages for cows and sheeps

Humans have encountered many large, dangerous animals in their history. Animals with whom they have competed for food and territory. Huge things with massive claws and teeth that couldn't possibly be outrun or outfought.

There also used to be several other kinds of hominid out there. Intelligent, tool using species.

Nowadays, the other hominids are long gone, and almost all of the hazardous megafauna have gone too. Don't steal sheep from the human villages. It will end very, very badly for you.

Answer (score 9):

### They're trappers.

Being able to relatively rapidly construct large-scale traps (in relation to the fauna) - be they of the body-gripping or deadfall type, trapping pits or pentraps - giants don't even have to get near their prey, and prefer catching larger amounts of live animals to minimize efforts and waste.

Answer (score 6):

**They don't hunt, they wait, watch the skies, listen and follow their noses.** - Slight frame-challenge.

Many herds of animals will roam for miles in search of water or grazing. Often they get picked-off by predators or just die of dehydration/disease/degenerate diseases associated with age.

The movement or presence of crows, vultures, hawks, condors, eagles, hyenas and coyotes all indicates the potential presence of fallen-flesh. Following these creatures is the key. Yep, they're scavengers and carrion-eaters, taking meat where they find it, fending-off predators from their kills, and other little creatures that might otherwise steal their meal. Their noses can smell that characteristic never-forgotten smell of death before it even takes the creature destined to become their next meal.

Comment: reminds me of the old theory of T-rexes being scanvangers, giant reptiles with fearsome weapons but too slow to hunt.

Comment: It reminds me what a lot of people thought (I believe) cave bears acted, or some sort of big extinct bear.